Blender - Cycles modifier for walk cycle make legs apart from each other
I've been trying to do a Walk cycle with a rig i found online using the Cycle modifiers - repeat with offset. The keyframes I set for the walk go from 1 to 25 and right after they end and the cycle is supposed to start, the legs start separating from each other. Any ideas?
Armature:


Feels like very little info, but I'm guessing that the first forward step has a slight sideways offset. If the animation keeps repeating and everything's supposed to accumulate, that would cause this effect. I am rather unfamiliar with the cycle animation modifier, and your rig is not shown, so IDK more.

hllo please share your armature: https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots done!

thanks but there is no action in the shared file, please share the armature with its action

@moonboots fixed, I apologize.

@Francia Santana your feet controllers are not aligned with the walk, that's why the feet go sideway, in Edit mode select Transform Orientations > Global, select each bone and SX0, also flatten their Z Location curve in the Graph Editor

Also I'm not sure why you use Cycles modifier instead of repeating the action with the NLA?

I'm not sure why you use Cycles modifiers to repeat your walk cycle, why don't you use the NLA?
Your problem is that the feet controllers are not aligned with the walk axis (they are slightly oblique), therefore to move them forward it needs keyframes on Y, and as their Y location keyframes are repeated with offset by the Cycles modifier, the bones drift away progressively. What you first need to do in Edit mode is scale them on the (global) X axis, SX0 so that they are correctly aligned:

Second thing to do, as, when the controller was oblique, you had to correct the bone Z location axis to make the foot go straight ahead, the action curve on this track is bumpy. To keep this Z location axis flat, go into the Graph Editor, make the tracks invisible except Z Location, select the keyframes and flatten them on the Graph Editor Y axis (SY0):

